# Rails 4 - alias_method in Concern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alias, activesupport-concern

I'm trying to add `alias_method :zzz_delete, :delete` to a Concern but it just doesn't work.
I have tried to wrap it in `included do`, `singleton_class.class_eval do`, `class << self` and various combination of all of those blocks.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

It's `alias_attribute` not `alias_method`. And then use `alias_attribute :zzz_delete, :delete` in your model and then use it in controller.

`alias_attribute` is used to assign a new name to the field.

Comment: Just to clarify, I'm trying to alias the method `Model#delete` to `Model#zzz_delete`, thank you for your input!

Comment: Actually, your solution seems to work! But are you sure I should use alias_attribute? Since other attr_accessor methods will be created, which is actually unwanted.. (`:zzz_delete, :zzz_delete=, :zzz_delete?`)

Comment: Also, if I want to `alias_attribute :zzz_destroy!, :destroy!` it will yield an error
So I think your solution is not really usable :(